# h2o deepwater from docker image in R

Tags: r, h2o

I can connect from R to h2o cluster which is running from docker image but there is error appearing:

`Version mismatch! H2O is running version 3.11.0.235 but h2o-R package is version 3.11.0.99999 .`

I can run many tasks from R but for example i can not run XGB training which I can run with Flow.
I want to create more comprehensive algorithm but I also need R functions to it.

I could not find h2o R package in version `3.11.0.235.`.
Is there option to use full potential of cluster h2o from R if cluster h2o is running from docker image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right package file is here:

```
/opt/dist/h2o_3.11.0.234.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `strict_version_check = FALSE` in your `h2o.init()` call and that will get you around the error.  Those versions are close enough that it shouldn't lead to any issues (but technically it could).

Also, that's an older Docker image -- the build number now is 274, so I would also suggest a `docker pull`, although it's not strictly necessary.  There's more info on the h2oai/deepwater [README](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater).

```
docker pull opsh2oai/h2o-deepwater
```

Comment: Thanks for information about new version of image, but I still cannot use functions which don't exist in R package version (XGB training).